# What's the difference between ON voltage and threshold voltage in FETs?

Tags: fet

In field-effect transistors (FETs), what's the difference between ON voltage, \$V_{\text{on}}\$, and threshold voltage, \$V_{\text{T}}\$?

Comment: Provide an example data sheet where these symbols are used.

Answer (score 6):

By itself a FET does not simply have an ON state and an OFF state.
A FET has a "sliding" state depending on what voltages and currents you apply to it.

When \$Vgs\$ becomes larger than \$Vt\$ a conductive channel forms between drain and source. *Does this mean there is no channel when \$Vgs < Vt\$ ?* NO it does not. \$Vt\$ is not a "hard" voltage, there is no sudden behavioural change (no discontinuity) when \$Vgs = Vt\$.

Regarding \$Von\$, it is what you define it to be. If I needed a LED to turn on and with my NMOS and it appears I need only Vgs = 1 Volt then I could say \$Von = 1 V\$.

Vt is a physical property of a MOSFET.

Von is a voltage you need to apply to the gate-source of a FET in order to get it in a certain state of conductivity (between drain and source). What this state is depends on someone's choice, not the MOSFET.

But a different Power MOSFET which controls a 100 A DC motor might need a Vgs of 10 V to turn ON then I would say \$Von = 10 V\$

Usually \$Von > Vt\$ as you want the FET to be sufficiently "ON" so that it can conduct some current.

Comment: Great answer. I think there's a typo, and since an edit from me requires a 6 char minimum change, and it is a 1 character edit, can you confirm the change instead? Was: "Does this mean there is no channel when Vgs,Vt?" Should be (I think): "Does this mean there is no channel when Vgs < Vt?" Agreed?

Comment: @SamGibson Well spotted, indeed a typo, I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When a FET is "barely on" it's high resistance. If subject to high current, this leads to considerable power dissipation, which can be a problem.

When a FET is "turned fully on" it's quite low resistance, and as a result can pass considerable current while dissipating very little power itself.

Looking at an [IRF 7101](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf7101.pdf), for example, VGS(th) is given as a minimum of 1 volt and a maximum of 3 volts, specified as ID=250µA with VDS=VGS. RDS(on) on the other hand, is specified only for VGS = 4.5V and 10V (and is lower at 10V). The resistance at "threshold" is thus 4000-12000 Ω while max RDS(on) is 0.15-0.10 Ω.

And, as Passerby subtly implies, there is no "V(on)" in the datasheet - just RDS(on) at the two GS voltages, which one could take to mean "V(on)" but that's not actually what they say, and depending on your use/needs, "V(on)" (as required to prevent excessive temperature rise in some application circuit) in one application might be 10V, while in another 5V would do.

Answer (score 0):

In the weak-strong model, \$V_{\text{on}}\$ is the theoretical point where inversion changes from weak to strong.

[image]([source](http://www.ele.uri.edu/Courses/ele447/Slides/DevicePhysicsI/chap3AllenHolberg.pdf))